# Want to make login component,but my admin component are effecting.like navbar is coming in that component

Tags: node.js, angular, mean-stack

I have 2 types of component,admin component which have all sidebar,header etc.
but now i make auth component and working on login.
but when i start making design..
that's master design of header and navbar is still coming.
How i can make that parent.or any other idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const routes: Routes = [
   path: '/admin',
   component: AdminComponent,
   children: [
      {
         path: '/dashboard',
         component: DashboardComponent
      },
   ],
   path: '/login',
   component: LoginComponent
];
```

You can have AdminComponent, all the pages inside AdminComponent children, which has sidebar, headers layout in it. While for login component, you can just have another layout.

Comment: how to ? /login is still getting app.component.html layout. how i can redirect so it load my new layout?

Comment: you should put the header, footer, sidebar etc. in AdminComponent, while the app.component.html remain empty